# Facing Issues while Overwrting a file

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, overwrite

I have a parquet file in which i am changing the schema of it(by casting string to integer).
i am overwriting the file like this
df2.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('s3://s3-tdh-infolake-test/vai/product_v1/Merged_202_product_v1_21')

but i am facing below error

```
22/11/09 11:51:05 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]22/11/09 11:51:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, ip-10-72-1-132.ec2.internal, executor 5): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileDownloadException: Failed to download file path: s3://s3-tdh-infolake-test/vai/product_v1/Merged_20221027093416_product_v1_21, range: 0-40863, partition values: [empty row], isDataPresent: false

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://s3-tdh-infolake-test/vai/product_v1/Merged_20221027093416_product_v1_21'
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:910)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.getFileStatus(EmrFileSystem.java:553)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.fromPath(HadoopInputFile.java:39)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:448)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildPrefetcherWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:595)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildPrefetcherWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$AsyncFileDownloader$$downloadFile(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader$$anonfun$initiateFilesDownload$2$$anon$1.call(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader$$anonfun$initiateFilesDownload$2$$anon$1.call(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 more


Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileDownloadException: Failed to download file path: s3://s3-tdh-infolake-test/vai/product_v1/Merged_20221027093416_product_v1_21, range: 0-40863, partition values: [empty row], isDataPresent: false
        at
```